# Unit testing of Services / Factories - AngularJS - Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, service, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I have some troubles writing tests for my services in my angularJS project. 
I am using Karma and Jasmine for my unit tests. 
To begin, I chose a service with no dependencies, but I never had passed the tests.

Here's my service ( written with coffeeScript )

```
angular.module('app').factory 'rankFactory', [ ->
  rankFactory = {}
  ranks = [
    {
      id: 0
      label: 'RANK0'
    }
    {
      id: 1
      label: 'RANK1'
    }
  ]

  rankFactory.getRanks = ->
    ranks

  rankFactory.getRanks = (id) ->
    ranks[id]

  rankFactory
 ]
```

The service works fine. Thus, the test doesn't. Here's my test :

```
describe('rank Factory unit tests', function(){
    describe  ('when I call myService rankFactory.getRanks ()', function() {

        beforeEach(module('app'));

            it('returns ranks', inject(function(rankFactory){
                expect(rankFactory.getRanks()).not.to.equal(null);
            }))
        }
    )
});
```

I have been trying for multiple hours, and read a lot of issues and documentation but still can not find out why it doesn't work. Can you help  me please?

----------------------------------------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------------------

I figured out that my issue is related with coffeeScript. 
My Controllers, services are written with coffeeScript and when I launch my tests, I got Syntax errors related to my services.

Here is my Config file :

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        '../bower_components/angular/angular.js',
        '../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
        '../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        '../src/scripts/**/*.coffee',
        '../src/scripts/Services/rankService.coffee',
        'unit-tests/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        '**/*.coffee': ['coffee']
    },

    coffeePreprocessor: {
      // options passed to the coffee compiler
      options: {
        bare: true,
        sourceMap: false
      },
      // transforming the filenames
      transformPath: function(path) {
        return path.replace(/\.coffee$/, '.js')
      }
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

I am writing my tests in javaScript and I am confused what do I have to do to make it cover CoffeeScript.

Ps : I have installed karma-coffee-preprocessor

Comment: "what is not working?", any errors in console?

Comment: have you added the particular file in your test case config?

Comment: @PankajParkar : I can not handle coffeeScript Controllers / Services

Comment: @Rohit , I made an update of my question and put my config test file. Can you tell me if I am doing it the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following example from [this tutorial](http://mcgivery.com/unit-testing-ionic-app/):

```
describe('Chats Unit Tests', function() {
    var Chats;
    beforeEach(module('starter.services'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_Chats_) {
        Chats = _Chats_;
    }));

    it('can get an instance of my factory', inject(function(Chats) {
        expect(Chats).toBeDefined();
    }));

    it('has 5 chats', inject(function(Chats) {
        expect(Chats.all().length).toEqual(5);
    }));
});
```

I would deduct that you need to do something like:

```
describe('rank Factory unit tests', function(){
    var factory;
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_rankFactory_) {
        factory = _rankFactory_;
    }));

    it('returns ranks', inject(function(factory) {
        expect(factory.getRanks()).not.to.equal(null);
    }));
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your response, I actually tried this, but didn't work as well. I think there's something I am missing or doing wrong

Comment: An actual error message that you get would be helpful to share. Also, if you can set up jsfiddle or something like that would allow us to help you better.

Comment: I found out that the problem was that my controllers are written in coffeeScript, My problem now is that I have syntax errors of my service while debugging tests that means  that it doesnt cover coffeescript files. I will update my question to clarify my isue